# Slurm Requested node configuration is not available

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

hello everyones so im trying to set up a new hpc cluster i made an account and added users and im using a partition but whenerver i run a job it gives me an error that request node configuration is not available i checked my slurm.conf but it seems good to me i need some help
the error `Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available`

```
   #
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#

SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
SlurmdSpoolDir=/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
#ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
#PluginDir=
#FirstJobId=
ReturnToService=2
#MaxJobCount=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PropagatePrioProcess=
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#SrunProlog=
#SrunEpilog=
#TaskProlog=
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=50
#TmpFs=
#UsePAM=
#
# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
#
# SCHEDULING
#SchedulerAuth=
#SchedulerPort=
#SchedulerRootFilter=
#PriorityType=priority/multifactor
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=14-0
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=14-0
#PriorityWeightFairshare=100000
#PriorityWeightAge=1000
#PriorityWeightPartition=10000
#PriorityWeightJobSize=1000
#PriorityMaxAge=1-0
#
# LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd

#JobCompType=jobcomp/filetxt
#JobCompLoc=/cm/local/apps/slurm/var/spool/job_comp.log

#
# ACCOUNTING
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
#JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/cgroup
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageUser=slurm
# AccountingStorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
# AccountingStoragePass=SLURMDBD_USERPASS

# This section of this file was automatically generated by cmd. Do not edit manually!
# BEGIN AUTOGENERATED SECTION -- DO NOT REMOVE
# Server nodes
SlurmctldHost=omics-master
AccountingStorageHost=master
# Nodes
NodeName=omics[01-05] Procs=48 Feature=local
# Partitions
PartitionName=defq Default=YES MinNodes=1 DefaultTime=UNLIMITED MaxTime=UNLIMITED AllowGroups=ALL PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 OverSubscribe=NO PreemptMode=OFF AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL Nodes=omics[01-05]
ClusterName=omics
# Scheduler
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
# Statesave
StateSaveLocation=/cm/shared/apps/slurm/var/cm/statesave/omics
PrologFlags=Alloc
# Generic resources types
GresTypes=gpu
# Epilog/Prolog section
Prolog=/cm/local/apps/cmd/scripts/prolog
Epilog=/cm/local/apps/cmd/scripts/epilog
# Power saving section (disabled)
# END AUTOGENERATED SECTION   -- DO NOT REMOVE
```

and this is my sinfo

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
defq*        up   infinite      5   idle omics[01-05]
```

and this is my test script

```
   #!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=2                       # Number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-socket=2
#SBATCH --output=std.out
#SBATCH --error=std.err
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1gb
echo "hello from:"
hostname; pwd; date;
sleep 10
echo "going to sleep during 10 seconds"
echo "wake up, exiting
```

"

and thanks in advance

Comment: This error simply means that you put the wrong information in your job script. Please update the question with the job script. Also, `sinfo` shows your HPC has only 1 partition?

Comment: if i delete the memory per cpu option it dosent show any error so i think thats the  problem im trying to find a way to fix it

Comment: in the slurm.conf file do i need to specify each node features like how many cpu they have and ram ??and if its true can some one gives me an example ?

Comment: do not touch `slurm.conf`. Yes may want to remove few lines that is not recognized.  SLURM systems are often customised by the organisation, so I can't tell which one is not implemented. Get support from your organisation. Here is a list of commands that `sbatch` supports. https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the node definition, you do not specify `RealMemory` so Slurm assumes the default of 1MB (!) per node. Hence the request of 1GB per CPU cannot be fulfilled.

You should run `slurmd -C` on the compute node, that will give you the line to insert in the `slurm.conf` file for Slurm to correctly know the hardware resources it can allocate.

```
$ slurmd -C | head -1
NodeName=node002 CPUs=16 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=1 RealMemory=128547
```

Comment: after the changes do i need to restart any kind of services ?

Comment: yes restart `slurmctld`